# How to load python modules in Rstudio instance

Tags: module, rstudio, rpython

Reproducible example.

From bash try:

```
$ R
> library(rPython)
> python.exec("help('modules')")
```

I get loads, e.g.

```
blaze               itertools           scipy               
blz                 itsdangerous        see
```

Now try the same in RStudio:

```
> library(rPython)
> python.exec("help('modules')")
```

Crash!

[image]

### Update

I've tried this on RStudio 0.99.451 (old dev version) and 0.99.467 (current latest - https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ ).

Comment: This executed successfully on OS X with the development version of RStudio. Can you provide more information on your platform + R's `sessionInfo()`? In addition, it looks like a separate error message was printed to the console but is cut off in your screenshot -- what was it?

Comment: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base